# Permanently turn off new Google Maps and go back to old one

Tags: google-maps

I found *new* Google Maps slow, useless (routes with only two points) and wrong. Is there any way, I can turn it off completely and go back to favored *old* Google Maps? Or is this — as with everything in Google — one way trip?

I found [Google Help](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3031966?hl=en&p=newmaps_no3d) text on this matter, but it seems useless. I have the feeling, that it discuss something completely different. It says about `lite indicator` in bottom-right corner. I don't have something like that. And provided links, that should switch new Google Maps engine between WebGL and canvas-based, simply doesn't work. All of them opens new window with annoying advertisment about new maps.

I even tried pasing part of URL, they're talking about (`force=canvas`) into any URL that my new Google Maps uses. Of course without any luck.

So... is there *any way*, I can get rid of *new Google Maps*, once and permanently?

**UPDATE**: In *these days* (April, 2015) Google [has announced](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6166252?p=update&hl=en&rd=1), that soon *new* Google Maps will be the only one available. To my extremely negative surprise, this question will become invalid soon! :(

Comment: The "New" Google Maps is now the default for everyone. It is entirely possible that the "old" Google Maps will no longer be available in the future.

Comment: Ah, conjecture.  As a comparison, consider Google Images, which still supports the old UI (via query string sout=1, e.g.) many years later.

Comment: @reisio I know perhaps you are making all of these comments tongue-in-cheek, but please be respectful at all times.

Comment: No, I'm serious. Respectful would be not wasting all our time by disallowing answers and deleting people's comments, but inexplicably (y'know, besides that you want your little badges and numbers to change :p) leaving irrelevant ones.

Comment: And now is the day, r.i.p. old google maps ! (ps. for now it is still possible to access it using the ?output=classic method)

Comment: Here's the bookmarlet I use to make the new google maps tolerable: javascript:(function(){uri='https://www.google.com/maps/';term='%s';if(term.indexOf('/')>=0){location.href=uri+'dir/'+term}else{location.href=uri+'place/'+term}})();

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**Update 2015-05-07:** With Google [finally removing](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/maps/Zgqoqsvfipc%5B1-25%5D) "classic" Google Maps, they have introduced "[Lite Mode](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3031966?hl=en)" as the alternative. You can access it via the menu as described in the link, or by adding `?force=lite` to the end of the URL, for example: https://www.google.com/maps/?force=lite

---

**Original answer**

According to [this Google Help article](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3045828?hl=en):

1. Go to http://maps.google.com.
2. Click the **Help** button (white question mark in a blue circle) at the bottom.
3. Click **Return to classic Google Maps**.
4. Click **Yes** in the notification bar that appears.
5. On the landing page that appears, follow the instructions to opt out permanently.

Any feedback you could provide as to why you wanted to opt out will be valuable in improving the product for you in the future.

Comment: Thanks! I just found this myself. The only problem was, that I was to hurry, and I was closing browser before "Updating preferences" page was fully loaded. Turns out, that you have to be patient at that.

Comment: I expect that this will be only temporary. They're not going to want to support two codebases forever.

Comment: I belive, you're right. Then, there'll be: "Google Maps, bye bye, OpenStreet Maps, welcome!". At least for me.

Comment: Here, on 2, the circle is black. And here 5 shows "You have switched back to classic Google Maps for this session. Do you want to make the switch permanent? Yes Dismiss" http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/4876/cxjd.png.

Comment: @Farhan I don't know, how does this look at your side, but on my side, I get "new" Google Maps "back again" only, when I clear all cookies in my browser. If I don't, the I see no enforcement from Google site and I'm usually sticking on "old" maps for as long as few months (until next cookie clear, anyway).

Comment: @trejder thanks for the update. I've also updated this answer to add details for "Lite mode" which will be the alternative when classic is removed.

Comment: Unfortunately the Lite mode is useless; it disables a bunch of features including a few necessary onces like dragging routes and destinations which were perfectly functional in the Classic version. As usual, Google makes a good thing, waits until users get used to it, then ruins it.

Answer (score 7):

If there is no option on google maps to revert to old version, you can use this webpage to opt out provided by google.com:

https://www.google.com/maps?output=classic&dg=opt

Comment: Clicking on that link takes you to old maps, but it shows a message similar to "Do you want to make this change permanent?" and you have to agree to it or next time it'll put you back in new maps app.

Comment: Thank you. This worked when Google's official method failed (because no elements on the new map page would respond).

Comment: That has stopped working now. `:-(`

Comment: Works for me right now, but It shows "new" maps with an additional information, that I'm using "light" version of "new" maps. Seems we have now **three** versions of Google Maps: old, new-light and new-full. Strange...

Answer (score 3):

Google has [made it clear](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6166252?p=update&hl=en&rd=1) that they were going to completely phase out the “Classic” Google Maps (Q2 2015). The vast majority of feedback has been negative towards the new Maps (I have yet to see a single positive comment), but per their history (and company policy?), they have no intention of listening to user feedback, so all methods of accessing the old Maps have stopped working.

No URL query term, no cookie, no user-agent hack, or browser extension can be used to access it anymore because they completely removed it now (think they “fixed” the loopholes that allowed people to access the old version).

There are innumerable people complaining about this in countless threads on more sites than there are stars in the sky, but if Google keeps with its tradition of ignoring user feedback, then all of the petitions in the world won’t get them to bring it back. The best you can hope for is to send feedback about very specific issues and hope they actually bother to read it.

Comment: (This whole question will—eventually—be a candidate for deletion once Google deletes Classic Maps.)

Comment: I recommend switching to [Bing Maps](http://www.bing.com/maps/) because that is much closer to “Classic” Google Maps than the New (or even Lite) Google Maps are.

Comment: Probably it will become obsolete at some time. You can then delete it (more details: [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256093/189165)). But, right now, it is the only valid one, so I'm accepting it.

Comment: If the old maps is gone, people might still search how to access it. And "it's not possible anymore" is a useful answer for those people. I don't see why it should be deleted.

Comment: @Synetech I used Bing for a while because of exactly this. Bing was faster to load and you could to multi point directions and searches very easily. But now Bing maps is just as slow as Google. Seems they both have decided slow is the way to go.