# How to enable new Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

How can I enable new Google Maps? It seems I’m still stuck with the old version. Can't find a link or switch. When I click “Try it now”, it takes me to the preview tour.

I’m from Canada; was it released just for US?

Comment: Does [this link](https://maps.google.com/maps/about/explore/?status=invite) asks you to login?

Comment: ok now it works ! From work the Try now button did not work.. thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing it from [this link](https://maps.google.com/maps/about/explore/?status=invite)—it should lead you to a login screen. After the login, you should be able to access the new version.

Answer (score 1):

I'd previously [disabled the new Google Maps "permanently"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/46952/22277) and clicking the various [links which were supposed to force it to reappear](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3031966?hl=en) failed as did the link in the other answer, always returning me to classic maps.

I had to clear all of my cookies for google.com and its subdomains in order to get the new Google Maps back.