# How to revert to old Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

How to change back to classic Google Maps?

(The old question is obsolete, and the topic is protected so I can't answer it with updated answer!!!)

Comment: By "the old question", you mean [Completely turn off new Google Maps and go back to old one](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46952/completely-turn-off-new-google-maps-and-go-back-to-old-one?rq=1)?

Comment: Yes, the topic was locked because a moderator were afraid someone would reply "thanks", and tarnish the sanctity of the forum discipline, so i couldnt honorably update the answer to this: https://www.google.com/maps?output=classic&dg=opt

Comment: @prehensile You may add your answer, but don't just leave the link there, explain what it does.

Comment: Oh ok i could answer, you can mask this version of the question if you want. thanks!, close and mark as duplicate. sorry about the complication.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy, I don't know why you couldn't find it yourself :)

[image]

Comment: because this option has dissapeared from the recent version? i have this, its different: http://www.hardwarezone.com.ph/files/img/2013/04/Screenshot_2013-05-15_at_12_38_58_AM.jpg

Comment: If there is no option on google maps to revert to old version, you can use this webpage to opt out:

https://www.google.com/maps?output=classic&dg=opt

Comment: @prehensile Is that the answer you were going to add to the old question?

Comment: yes that is the answer.The round question mark doesn't appear for me so the previous answer was not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no option on google maps to revert to old version, you can use this webpage to opt out provided by google.com:

https://www.google.com/maps?output=classic&dg=opt